# Method Mockito.spy() call real method?

Tags: java, mockito

I have 3 methods. When run unit test I need the next:

1. Method `serviceMethod_1` not call real method
2. Method `serviceMethod_2` call real method
3. Method `serviceMethod_1` call real method

Here definition of method `Mockito.spy()`

```
Mockito.spy() - each method implementation are the real one, except if you have defined a mocked behaviour with when(..)
```

That's exactlty what I need.

So here my unit test:

```
import org.mockito.Spy;
@Spy
private MyServiceImpl myServiceSpy;

@Before
    public void setup() {
        System.out.println("\nSETUP");
    }

    @Test
    public void myService_method_1_spy() {
        when(myServiceSpy.serviceMethod_1())
                .thenReturn("call_serviceMethod_1_MOCK");

        List<String> actualList = myServiceSpy.performService();
        

        List<String> expectedList = Arrays.asList(
                "call_serviceMethod_1_MOCK",
                "call_serviceMethod_2_REAL",
                "call_serviceMethod_3_REAL");
        assertEquals(expectedList, actualList);
       
        verify(myServiceSpy, times(1)).serviceMethod_1();
    }
```

Here service class:

```
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    private String text;

    @Override
    public String serviceMethod_1() {
        String result = "call_serviceMethod_1_REAL";
        System.out.println("serviceMethod_1: result = " + result);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String serviceMethod_2() {
        String result = "call_serviceMethod_2_REAL";
        System.out.println("serviceMethod_2: result = " + result);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String serviceMethod_3() {
        String result = "call_serviceMethod_3_REAL";
        System.out.println("serviceMethod_3: result = " + result);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> performService() {
        System.out.println("performService: START, this.className = " + this.getClass().getName()); // In the name contain word "MockitoMock"
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String item_1 = serviceMethod_1();
        String item_2 = serviceMethod_2();
        String item_3 = serviceMethod_3();
        list.add(item_1);
        list.add(item_2);
        list.add(item_3);
        return list;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

But when I run test I get the next output:

```
SETUP
serviceMethod_1: result = call_serviceMethod_1_REAL
performService: START, this.className = com.myproejctjava.javatestproject.service.MyServiceImpl$MockitoMock$Il2iukBL
serviceMethod_2: result = call_serviceMethod_2_REAL
serviceMethod_3: result = call_serviceMethod_3_REAL
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
```

As you can see in the test call REAL method `serviceMethod_1`.

Why method `spy()` not help me? I need to not call real method `serviceMethod_1`

Comment: but does the test fail?? (expected list, verify) ...or is just the output confusing?

Comment: @xerx593  test success passed. I'm confusing of output

Comment: (but actually the code is "bad testable"..instead of investing time in powermocking, you should consider to improve on that;)

Comment: As @xerx593 says, wanting to do this is a symptom that you haven't written your code with testability in mind. You should refactor it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
doReturn("call_serviceMethod_1_MOCK").when(myServiceSpy).serviceMethod_1();
```

Instead of

```
when(myServiceSpy.serviceMethod_1()).thenReturn("call_serviceMethod_1_MOCK");
```

Comment: yes, this seems the desired/an "Important Gotcha", https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13